# Updating a document in elastic search when the document id is automatically generated

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have the following script which I use to insert json document's into my elastic search database.

```
for file in /home/ec2-user/Workspace/met_parts/*
 do curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/ABCD/met/" -d @$file
done
```

I have a list of 'n' files inside my `met_parts` folder each file containing on JSON record as below.

```
        {
            "Application": "xxxxxxxx", 
            "FirstTime": 1425502958958, 
            "LastHost": "127.0.0.1", 
            "Transactions": "88654"
        }
```

My `met_parts` folder gets updated once every hour.So I need to run the above script once every hour.When I do `curl -XPOST` a second time, I want the existing document to be updated, rather than a new object to be inserted. How do I achieve this? Since I am using `XPOST` the `document id` is automatically generated by elastic search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot update a document without the `id`. You should create document with `id` so that you know which document to update later. You can use the following command to index a document with a given id.

```
POST <index name>/<type name>/<document id>
{
    ...
}
```

Note that you can also use a string for document id.